# Create view with subquery

Tags: sql, select, view

I'm trying to create a view in SQL Server but the syntax keeps give me issues due to the sub query I'm using. Basically I need the results of select statement below to be in a view. How would I go about this syntactically?

```
SELECT Sub_Company, GL_Account, CAST(SUM(Debits) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Debits, 
       CAST(SUM(Credits) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Credits, CAST(SUM([P&L_Impact]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [P&L_Impact], COUNT(*) AS Record_Count
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM [FL_SQL_Training].[dbo].[Combined_GL]
      WHERE Company = 'US' AND GL_Source = 'Consolidation'
     ) A
WHERE GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%UK%' OR
      GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%CAD%' OR
      GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%MEX%' OR
      GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%Hon%'
GROUP BY Sub_Company, GL_Account
```

Comment: You would add `create view <view name> as` before the `select`.

Comment: Probably the problem is to have view with parameters. Then you need table valued function instead. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396